# Why doesn't my Google home page work properly?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-search

I've recently formatted my PC and during the reinstalling of all programs I came across some issues with my browsers and specifically with the Chrome address bar.

- My Google page doesn't seem to be as usual. It misses the bottom bar and the button on the top right corner which allows to show all Google's services.
- Also, when I try to search something in Google through Chrome's search bar at the top it does not work. It sends me to the Google's home page again and I'm forced to search what I'm looking for in the Google bar at the center.

I underline that I get this issue with all the browsers because I tried with IE too.

Here is a screenshot of how the Google page looks:

> [image]

and here is how Chrome looks when I try to search anything through the Chrome's URL bar:

> [image]

Comment: You've cropped the address bar, please include it in the screenshot too. You can [edit] your question.

Comment: @gronostaj just edited. I hope now it's fine :)

Comment: Could you try google.com instead of google.it?

Comment: @thilinaR how do I go in google.com? By typing it into the Chrome's address bar I get redirected in google.it. The top bar shows google.com but it appears "Google Italia" at the center.
The page still looks the same anyhow

Comment: try google.com/ncr

Comment: tried google.com/ncr but still redirected to Google Italia

http://imgur.com/WeLuH7X

Comment: the screenshot on the link in ur latest comment shows that its on google.com

Comment: Ok but the page still looks the same. By searching around on the Internet I found the issue should be caused by Windows 7 Home Premium. It's kind of an incompatibility I think, but I'm not sure :/

Comment: Found the solution! Cause of the issue is Windows 7 Home Premium. I've tried to install Windows 7 Ultimate and everything works perfectly!